# Git: How do I remove a whole bunch of file changes and untracked files that are not meant to be part of my branch?

Tags: git

I tried to update my branch from master, but must have screwed something up (I don't know what). Now I have about 20 modified and untracked files I do not want in my branch.

How can I go back to the last commit or push I made, before I tried to update?

I've tried

`git checkout 12345`, getting the hash from `git log` but the files are still present.

Would anyone know what I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `git reset --hard <commit_number>` on your branch.

Alternatively if you want to go back to your last pushed version, you can try

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

But please be mindful that this will **erase** all your untracked code **permanently**.

For more info, you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114122/8556538)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it looks to me like you're asking how to preform a hard reset on your local repository. Consider This:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

If you're working from a branch, then replace "master" with whatever branch you're working out of. This will clean your current file structure and replace it with your last push to the origin.

**NOTE: All Local Changes will Be Lost.**

Hope this Helps!